# How do you save a setquery count to a string in Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
 QSqlQueryModel * model=new QSqlQueryModel ();
    int i,id;
    QString count;
    model->setQuery("SET '"+count+"' =(SELECT COUNT(*) from COLLABORATEUR)");

   qInfo() << count;
```

i tried this code but count is still clear i always get ""
i tried it like this too:

```
model->setQuery("SELECT '"+count+"'=COUNT(*) from COLLABORATEUR");
```

and like this :

```
model->setQuery("SELECT @count=COUNT(*) from COLLABORATEUR");
```

but count is still empty

Comment: you set it in the model, now your model knows count. you `setQuery` and you can get it by [query](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to count the number of records, then use directly `rowCount()`.

```
QString count = QString::number(model->rowCount());
qInfo() << count;
```